# Laravel Eloquent finding for "is null" in query many to many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models in Laravel with belongsToMany statement:

- Company:

```
public function game () {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class, 'linkccompaniesgames', 'CompaniesId', 'GamesId');
}
```

- Game

```
public function company () {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'linkcompaniesgames', 'GamesId', 'CompaniesId');
}
```

I don´t have problem to insert registers in this table, this process is ok. But when I try to select the games of some company, the Laravel brings a empty array. I see the problem in query but can't solve with Laravel:

select * from `Games` inner join `linkcompaniesgames` on `Games`.`id` = `linkcompaniesgames`.`GamesId` where `linkcompaniesgames`.`CompaniesId` is null

Laravel is finding for a null CompanyId but need to be "= 27" (for example).

```
$company = Company::find(27)->game()->toSql();
print_r($company);
```

The "find(27)" is normally returning a company.

Can anyone help me? Thank u!

Expecting return the games of the company 27, for example.

Comment: relace toSql with get. toSql is used to create sql query string.

Comment: what is the 'id' field named for the "companies" table?  also it would be wise to name these relationships in the plural since they return many